# Prompted for username/password when clicking print button in SSRS Report Viewer

Tags: iis-7, reportviewer

We are in the process of upgrading servers from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 R2 and from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008 R2.  Our applications are all web based.  For the most part we have been successful in the transition, but our report viewer seems to be causing some issue.  We have gone through the process of adding the handler definition to the system.webserver container in the web.config to make it work with IIS 7.5.  The reports render correctly with parameters and without, and are able to be exported without issue.  Our problem is that when we click on the Print icon to print the report we are presented with a Windows Security dialog box asking for a username and password.  The context of the prompt is my web server.

I've found a lot of documentation on getting the username/password prompt when linking directly to a report or when initially rendering the report in the report viewer, but I have not been able to find anything about the username/password prompt occurring solely when the print icon is clicked. I feel like this is probably some silly configuration setting somewhere but I am unable to find it.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
Let me also note that this is pointing to an SSRS server and not to embeded RDLC reports in the application itself.  Looking through fiddler, the 401 is for:
GET /Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ReportSession=qqmrflihqpiu4c45hoqlxt45&ControlID=f029b0c1-7a9e-4a61-9750-4a53d5eb0087&Culture=1033&UICulture=1033&ReportStack=1&OpType=PrintHtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out Report Viewer version 8 is not compatible with SSRS 2008 R2.  The resolutin to this is to upgrade the viewer.  I upgraded mine to version 10 and it works flawlessly.  I hope this helps someone else